# Black screen after booting.

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

My PC: Pentium 4, 2GB RAM, 32 bit, currently no OS

I installed Lubuntu 14.04.5 from a bootable USB. When I restarted the computer, it stuck at black screen. Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> combination. After that this text is being displayed:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

Being a beginner, I don't know what to do.

Comment: This key combination generally either opens up GUI mode or TTY mode. But in tty first line is something like `hostname login:`. Is your username and hostname lubuntu? I doubt that your installation wasn't successful and still in Live Mode.

Comment: `lubuntu@lubuntu:~$`??? I think it means you are on live DVD/USB and not on installed Ubuntu.

Comment: @Kulfy you are right. My hostname is Lubuntu but my username is Kunal.

Comment: @KunalJ It seems unclear to me. Are you still in Live mode?

Comment: No @Kulfy I have installed it completely and not in Live mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try Ctrl + Alt + F7 to go to the graphic window if one is running.
Ctrl + Alt + F1 or F2 or F3 will get independent terminals and you can switch among each other.

Comment: Malaya, in F7 there is only a black screen shown. Although I can open other TTYs but not the graphical interface.